# App freezes after trying to use camera in iOS simulator even with do catch handling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, camera

I am trying to add camera functionality to my app in swift 3. Since the iOS simulator has no camera, I wrote a do catch to allow the app to continue running after it fails to use the camera in the simulator.

```
do{
    let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
    captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)

}catch{
    print("there was an error adding camera as input:  ")
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

the error returned is "Cannot Record". However, this just freezes the app completely. Am I missing something in my error handling or is this an unavoidable side effect of using simulator?

Comment: What is your code for opening the Camera app?  I did something similar with Phone and Email, and I just used `UIAlertController` and other corresponding features to display that the code was opening another app.  Would something like that work? (ie- `@IBAction func` that acts when camera button is tapped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a thrown exception. You must not use AVCaptureDeviceInput on the simulator *at all*.

Use `#if arch(x86_64)` to avoid having any code involving the camera even be *present* when compiling for the simulator.

Comment: Well the main part is that it doesn't work on the simulator which is what I was originally asking  and you answered but you added something extra that I thought might be wrong

Comment: @Ineedhelp Modern iPhones are 64-bit, but their architecture is `arm64`, not `x86_64`. The `x86_64` architecture specifically refers to 64-bit x86 machines (e.g. desktops and laptops).